# Can a DAC produce only positive output?

Tags: dac, waveform

I'm working on a project requiring production of sinusoidal waves. Normally, from my understanding, a DAC can produce a waveform that alternates between a negative voltage and a positive voltage, but for my needs I need the DAC to produce a waveform that alternates between a zero voltage and a positive voltage.

Is this possible using a DAC, and if not how would I produce such a waveform?

Comment: It depends on DAC. There are many kinds of DACs. Select one with only positive output.

Comment: Choose your DAC - most do what you want.

Comment: Many, if not most, are positive only but bi-polar ones exist, especially for audio.

Comment: Digikey lists about [13000 DACs](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-digital-to-analog-converters-dac/701?k=dac).

Comment: Of these VERY ROUGHLY [about 1600](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-digital-to-analog-converters-dac/701?k=dac&k=&pkeyword=dac&sv=0&pv346=1351&pv346=1352&pv346=1353&pv346=1421&pv346=1422&pv346=1423&pv346=1424&pv346=1425&pv346=1493&pv346=1502&pv346=1506&pv346=1507&pv346=1522&pv346=1527&pv346=1528&pv346=1567&pv346=1626&pv346=1867&pv346=2374&pv346=2376&pv346=2378&pv346=2394&pv346=2396&pv346=2496&pv346=2650&pv346=2654&pv346=2658&sf=0&FV=-8%7C701&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) have bipolar supplies, and the balance have unipolar outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DACs are conventionally single polarity and made bipolar with an Op Amp and bipolar supply.

*Digikey has about 10% of its unique p/n's for DAC in bipolar (771 of 7441 , others are duplicates but currently stock only 335 of 2,472)* That should be enough to choose from ;)

To appease others who might want to make a bipolar DAC.
 [Falstad Sim
Proof](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.634267539816555%2057%205%2050%0Av%2096%20272%2096%20208%200%204%2040%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Ag%2096%20272%2096%20320%200%0Ar%2096%20144%20192%20144%200%2010000%0Ar%20192%20144%20336%20144%200%2010000%0Aw%20336%20144%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20192%20112%20192%20144%200%0Aw%20192%20144%20192%20176%200%0Aw%2096%20208%20192%20208%200%0Aa%20192%20192%20336%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%203.8229973467377247%203.8229999927324183%201000000%0AO%20336%20192%20400%20192%201%0AR%2096%20144%2064%20144%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ao%200%2064%200%204354%205%200.025%200%202%200%203%0Ao%209%2064%200%204354%205%200.00009765625%201%201%0A)

Offset -5V from Vref =+5V of DAC . (Or any Vref used by DAC for lower supplies.

Gain =2 to generate +/-5V using a 0~5V sawtooth sweep and CMOS RRIO Op AMP using +/-5V supplies.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110524/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75-can-a-dac-produce-only-pos).